# Is it possible to Pass $event from cshtml into Vue.component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, razor, emit

I want to pass an event into my vue.componenet, I have tried different ways but it all got "TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined"

Here is my Vue.componenet:

```
Vue.component('jl-asset-list', {
created() {
    console.log(this.asset);
    console.log(this.canModify);
    console.log(this.editSiteAssetAllowed);
    console.log(this.event);
},
props: {
    hasCompleteTask: {
        default: false,
        type: Boolean
    },
    asset: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
    }
},
methods: {
    EditSiteAsset(asset, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        var context = this;
        context.SelectedSiteAsset = asset;

        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var icon = $(target).closest('.jobasset_edit');

        icon.prop('disabled', true);
        this.$emit('edit-site-asset', asset);
    },
    EditJobAsset(asset) {
        this.$emit('edit-job-asset', asset);
    },
    HighlightAsset(asset) {
        this.$emit('highlight-asset', asset);
    }
}
```

My CSHTML:

```
<jl-asset-list v-for="(siteAsset, index) in FilteredSiteAssets" 
                                           inline-template 
                                           v-bind:asset="siteAsset" 
                                           v-bind:canModify="Model.CanModify"
                                           v-bind:editSiteAssetAllowed="Model.EditSiteAssetAllowed"
                                           v-on:highlight-asset="HighlightAsset" 
                                           v-on:edit-site-asset="EditSiteAsset">
                                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Asset/Templates/_AssestList.cshtml")
                            </jl-asset-list>
```

My template:

```
<a v-on:click="EditSiteAsset(asset)" 
       class="jobasset_edit jl-icon-orange" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Edit">
        <i class="mdi mdi-pencil-circle mdi-24px"></i>
    </a>
```

If I use EditSiteAsset($event) in v-on, and in vue.component's method is this.$emit('edit-site-asset', asset);, it wont work either.

My method EditSiteEvent() needs an event to operate

```
EditSiteAsset: function (data, event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        var context = this;
        context.SelectedSiteAsset = data;

        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var icon = $(target).closest('.jobasset_edit');

        icon.prop('disabled', true);

        GetSwitchModalPartial(
            '/Asset/UpdateSiteAsset?siteId=' + context.Model.SiteId + '&id=' + data.Id,
            { forJobAsset: true },
            function (data) {
                icon.prop('disabled', false);
            });
        return false;
    },
```

Comment: what makes you think EditSiteAsset is called with a second argument?

Comment: It should have a props "event" in the vue component as well and then I pass $event from cshtml to props "event" with v-bind,  and then my template I will call v-on:click="EditSiteAsset(asset, event)"  but it did not work well, so now in my template i just only call EditSiteAsset(asset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
    <a v-on:click="EditSiteAsset(asset, $event)">
        <i class="mdi mdi-pencil-circle mdi-24px"></i>
    </a>
```

`$event` is not "prop" in classic Vue terminology, its just special keyword you can use to pass DOM event when setting up inline DOM event listener

...also, you can remove following code from your event handler

```js
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

if you use [event modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) like this:

```html
    <a v-on:click.prevent.stop="EditSiteAsset(asset, $event)">
        <i class="mdi mdi-pencil-circle mdi-24px"></i>
    </a>
```

Comment: @Micheal_Levy If I wanted to do this the other way round that is catch an event from vue on a razor page, what would I need to do.

Comment: @DonaldN.Mafa Hard to say without more detais - you probably should write a separate question. Vue events are not really an "events" - they are really an event handlers (Vue attaches to a DOM event and executes JS function as a reaction).

Comment: @Micheal_Levy Thank you for your response. I have posted with a bit of explanation at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75789559/vue-composition-api-how-emit-events-and-values-to-a-razor-page