# Vue Composition API how emit events and values to a Razor Page?

Tags: vue.js, razor, vue-component, vuejs3, devextreme

I have a simple use case whereby on a page built with ASP.NET Razor, I have embedded a Vue component. Due to the complexity of the existing, we have opted to add Vue using components. On the Vue screen I have a DataGrid with a Panel at the top to load data based on periods. On the Razor page I have an existing report that needs to get values from this panel and load the grid accordingly. I am stuck on how to achieve, that is how do I emit events and props from my Vue component to let it to know what the newly selected value is for example, and once i have done that, what do I need  to do on the Razor page to reload my view component:

Vue component:

```
<template>
    <DxForm :col-count="1"
            :show-colon-after-label="true"
            :show-validation-summary="true"
            :columnWidth="100"
            @field-data-changed="handleFieldDataChanged">
        <DxGroupItem :col-count="3">
            <DxItem data-field="ViewType"
                    editor-type="dxLookup"
                    :label="{ text: formatMessage('lblSelectView') }"
                    :editor-options="{ items: viewTypes, valueexpr: 'value', displayexpr: 'text' }">
            </DxItem>
            <DxItem data-field="equityGoalLookup"
                    editor-type="dxLookup"
                    :label="{ text: formatMessage('lblSelectGoal') }"
                    :editor-options="{ dataSource: goalPeriodDataStore, valueExpr: 'value', displayExpr: 'text' }"
                    :visible="goalSelectVisible">
                <DxLabel text="Select Goal" />
            </DxItem>
            <DxItem data-field="targetLookup"
                    editor-type="dxLookup"
                    :label="{ text: formatMessage('lblSelectTarget') }"
                    :editor-options="{ dataSource: targetPeriodDataStore, valueExpr: 'value', displayExpr: 'text' }"
                    :visible="targetSelectVisible">
                <DxLabel text="Select Target" />
            </DxItem>
            <DxItem data-field="compareToActuals"
                    editor-type="dxCheckBox"
                    :label="{ text: formatMessage('lblCompareActuals') }"
                    :visible="compareToActualsVisible">
            </DxItem>
```

..............................................................................

```
        setup(props, { emit }) { 
            const area = "Company.EmploymentEquityValue";
            initLocale(area);

            const panelHandleChange = (event: any) => {
                emit("customChange", event.target.value)
            }
            return {
                panelHandleChange
            }


    function onHandleFieldDataChanged(e: FieldDataChangedEvent) {
        employmentEquityService.HandleFieldDataChanged(e);

        emit("goalPeriodId", e.value);
        emit("targetPeriodId", e.value);
        console.log(props.filterPanel);
        if (props.filterPanel) {
            props.filterPanel.goalPeriodId = e.value;
        }
    }
```

Razor Page:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        DevExpress.Analytics.Utils.ajaxSetup.ajaxSettings.headers = DevExpress.Analytics.Utils.ajaxSetup.ajaxSettings.headers || {};
        DevExpress.Analytics.Utils.ajaxSetup.ajaxSettings.headers["X-Parameters"] = "@Model.Parameters";
    </script>
}
<script type="module" src="~/pages/company-employment-equity-plan.js"></script>

<page-content>
    <div class="panel-box">
        <div class="panel-box__content">
            <div class="panel-box__body">
                <company-employment-equity-plan 
                    allow-edit=@Model.AllowEdit
                    api-endpoint="@Url.Action("Get", "EquityValueApi")"
                    api-equity-plan-goal-endpoint="@Url.Action("GetEquityPlanGoals", "EquityValueApi")"
                    api-equity-plan-target-endpoint="@Url.Action("GetEquityPlanTargets", "EquityValueApi")"
                    :filter-panel=@Model />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:700px;">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("ReportViewer", new
               {
                    Name = "EmploymentEquityPlanGoalVsActual/EmploymentEquityPlanGoalVsActual.repx",
                   Parameters = $"CompanyId={6464}&EffectiveDate=2023-02-01&UserId={Model.UserId}&pkEquityPlanPeriodIDGoal={Model.GoalPeriodId}",
                   ShowParameters = false
               })
    </div>

    <script type="text/html" id="equity-report"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
</page-content>
```

I also need to toggle whether to show the report or grid, therefore I need to pass when the checkbox is changed too? I need to pass the parameters from the Vue component to the report and load it again somehow

Comment: Vue cant' communicate with Razor Page directly - Razor is rendered on the server, Vue is rendering client side (using JavaScript running inside the browser). So unless the  `ReportViewer` has any JavaScript API, you are out of luck imho

Comment: Thank you, I now understand better.I had to end up using dispatchEvent from my Vue component to get it to work and a listener on the Razor page